# Why is this entangled?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I am studying a book of quantum computing and the author gives an example of a four qubits separable! He writes:

> Let $\left|ψ\right> = \frac 1 2(\left|00\right> + \left|11\right> +
>  \left|22\right> + \left|33\right>)   = 1/2 \, (\left|0000\right> +
>  \left|0101\right> + \left|1010\right> + \left|1111\right>)$.
>
> There are other decompositions with respect to which this state is
>   unentangled. For example, $\left|ψ\right>$ can be expressed as the product of
>   two two-qubit states:
>
> $\left|ψ\right> = \frac 1 2(\left|0_1\right> \left|0_2\right>\left|0_3\right>\left|0_4\right> +\left|0_1\right>\left|1_2\right>\left|0_3\right>\left|1_4\right>
>  +\left|1_1\right>\left|0_2\right>\left|1_3\right>\left|0_4\right> + \left|1_1\right>\left|1_2\right>\left|1_3\right>\left|1_4\right> =  \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(\left|0_1\right>\left|0_3\right> +\left|1_1\right>\left|1_3\right>)⊗\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} (\left|0_2\right>\left|0_4\right> +\left|1_2\right>\left|1_4\right>)$,
>
> where the subscripts indicate which qubit we are talking about. So
>   $\left|ψ\right>$ is not entangled with respect to the system decomposition
>   consisting of a subsystem of the first and third qubit and a subsystem
>   consisting of the second and fourth qubit. On the other hand, the
>   reader can check that $\left|ψ\right>$ is entangled with respect to the
>   decomposition into the two two-qubit systems consisting of the first
>   and second qubits and the third and fourth qubits.

I do not understand why
$$
\left|\psi\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\left|0_1\right>\left|0_3\right> + \left|1_1\right>\left|1_3\right>\right)\otimes
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (\left|0_2\right>\left|0_4\right> +\left|1_2\right>\left|1_4\right>)$$

And why it is true that "$\left|ψ\right>$ is entangled with respect to the decomposition into the two two-qubit systems consisting of the first and second qubits and the third and fourth qubits."?

Comment: It's fairly easy to mathematically verify that the equalities given hold true, remembering that $\otimes$ distributes over addition the normal way. Are you just looking for a more intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 2):

To address the intuitive side of the problem, think of four parties. Party 1 and 3 share a Bell state, and party 2 and 4 share another Bell state. Ten the four parties share exactly the state you've been given.

Now the first question is: If you look at parties 1 and 2 on one side, vs. 3 and 4 on the other side, do they share entanglement? Well, sure they do, they share two bell pairs: One between party 1 (left side) and party 3 (right side), and one between party 2 (left side) and party 4 (right side).

However now you regroup the parties, with party 1 and 3 on one side, and party 2 and 4 on the other side. And again you ask whether both sides share entanglement. And now the answer is no: While party 1 and 3 share a Bell pair, they are both on the same side, so that Bell pair is not shared between the sides. The same is true for the Bell pair between party 2 and party 4. There is no other entanglement besides those Bell pairs, and therefore there is no entanglement between those two sides.

Here's a graphical representation:
[image: graphical representation of the state and the two splits]

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, it's trivial to verify that the equality holds by distributing $\otimes$ over $+$. Remember the notation is $\left|abcd\right> = \left|a_1\right>\left|b_2\right>\left|c_3\right>\left|d_4\right>$, and you quickly get to the original form of $\psi$.

Intuitively, notice that there are four states the wavefunction allows with equal amplitude (and probability). These states all have the following properties: the first and third bit are equal, and the second and fourth bit are equal. So there are two independent degrees of freedom, given by the first (third) and second (fourth) bits. You can represent $\psi$ by writing out all possible states, but equally well by separating the system into these independent degrees of freedom. This is what is done in the final equality given.

The requirement that the first and third qubits must be the same is referred to as "entanglement" - those two qubits are entangled. The second and fourth qubits are also entangled. All he's saying in that last sentence you asked about is that the system is "entangled" in the sense that there are two pairs of entangled qubits in it.